# How To Create iFrames or Frames like StumbleUpon and Linkedin in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iframe, frame

I am developing my site. I am using Thestyle Wordpress theme in it. My every post is redirected to some other websites. And as they are redirecting I am loosing visitors to other site, I want to keep visitors on my site by in such a way that the external url opens in my site url.

Eg: stumbleupon - http://www.stumbleupon.com/su/1J1krv...com/gag/207886

Linkedin: http://www.linkedin.com/news?actionB...1eZ7X_46a_NkY1

I want to add same top heading bar like this sites do.

How can I do this?

---

I just searched plenty of sites which was telling how to use lightbox to open other pages.. but its not fully workable. I am a newbie in coding. Is there any other way to open such kind of things?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using a plug-in like gallery,light box, that will open URLs (as well as images) into a shadow box within your site

Comment: Ok.. Let Me try that... Otherwise I am thinking to convert my WOrdperss theme into Static HTML..